# How I can put dates in two category Spring and Fall?

Tags: php, date

How can I put dates in two categories Spring and Fall??

I have the dates in the table like this

```
2012-08-27 
2011-01-12 
2011-08-27  
2010-01-12
2010-08-27
2009-01-12
2009-08-27
```

When I retrieve them from the table I need to put them like "SPRING 2010","Fall 2010"

The day of 27th always means FALL and the Day of 12th always means SPRING

I need to extract the year and check whether it's fall or spring and output like  "SPRING 2010","Fall 2010"

Please help on how to make this happen? Thank you.

Comment: `substr($date, -2)` will contain either 27 or 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = '2012-08-27'; // your initial string

$year = substr($string,0,4); //$year = '2012'
$season = (substr($string,-2)=='27' ? 'FALL' : 'SPRING'); //$season = 'FALL'
$full = $season.' '.$year; //$full = 'FALL 2012'

echo $full; //will output 'FALL 2012'

//as a function
function season_year($n){
    //if 27 = fall
    #return ((substr($n,-2)=='27' ? 'FALL' : 'SPRING').' '.substr($n,0,4));
    //if 27 = spring
    return ((substr($n,-2)=='27' ? 'SPRING' : 'FALL').' '.substr($n,0,4));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly. Can you please tell me how to reverse it?? For example if the given string is "Fall 2012"  The day of 27th always means FALL and the Day of 12th always means SPRING

Comment: See my edit - I commented out the original and added the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Using mysql you can do as

```
select 
 case 
   when day(date_field) = '27' then concat('Fall',' ',year(date_field))
   when day(date_field) = '12' then concat('Spring',' ',year(date_field))
 end as `display`
from table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the dates and use explode to extracts date like.

```
foreach($dates as $date){

 list($year,$month,$day) = explode('-', $date)
 if($day == '27'){
   $season = 'FALL '.$year;
 }else{
   $season = 'SPRING '.$year;
 }
```